# how to know the count of words starting with a particular word in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using a mysql database for storing the data. The table consists of 2 columns `s_no` and `name`. I used index on this table on name. Now I want to get only words starting with a particular letter say "a" or "b" etc. How can I do it? Is there any SQL query for retrieving data in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select s_no,name from tablename where name like 'a%' or name like 'b%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name
where name like 'a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tablename where name like 'a%'
```

You can also pass the value inside parameters

```
@value varchar(50)

Select * from tablename where name like @value
```

so whatever characters u insert like a or b just mearge it with `%` and here you go

like `@value=@value+ '%'` before query .

Answer (score 0):

```
select s_no,name from table where name like 'a%' or name like 'b%'
```